# Elimination of const copy of variable

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I was reviewing some code. There I saw this:

```
int Obj::GetValue() const
{
   return m_val;
}

void SomeFunc(const Obj *obj1)
{
   // keep a copy in case obj1 is modified!
   const Obj o2 = *obj1;
   //... much more code
   // some which may modify data pointed to by obj1
   DoSomething(o2.GetValue());    // use original value!
}
```

can a compiler optimize this code such that o2.GetValue() will end up being replace by `obj1->GetValue()` or some cached value ?

Obj1 points to some memtable, the pointer remains valid through the function, but the memtable data can change synchronously due to some call within the function that operate on the memtable which incidentally is global!
this is why the dev took a copy of Obj1, but because he was not planning on modifying it he decided to declare it const.

I think that because we point to a const object, and the copied object is const then the optimiser can decide to optimize out the copy

I've checked with godbolt.org using: gcc, clang & msvc as our code is multi platform, and all seems good. But of course if this code is UB, I will ask for it to be changed.

Comment: `But of course if this code is UB` at which part of this code do you think that you have UB?

Comment: I don't think there's any UB here, and if `obj1` or `*obj1` can get modified then I don't think the compiler is allowed to optimize `o2.GetValue()` to `obj1->GetValue()`.

Comment: As it stands the complier will reject this code for discarding qualifiers. Needs to be `int Obj::GetValue() const`

Comment: Does your code actually "modifiy the data pointed to by obj1", which is a pointer to `const Obj`?

Comment: @Bob__ Even then the compiler could use `obj1->GetValue()` instead of `o2.GetValue()` before that value is changed save that value in a register and pass it then to `DoSomething`. If this will happen or if it makes sense to do so, would be a compiler-specific question.

Comment: ...Or instead of copying the whole object, just store `const int val=obj1->GetValue();` before modifying `obj1`, but there's surely a reason if OP can't do that.

Comment: @Bob__ yes Obj1 point to some memtable (a vector) and some call can modify the data in the memtable. The pointer will remain valid. 
What I'm wondering is: the compiler sees both const, so from its point of view it does not matter where it fetch the value as they should be both the same!

Comment: @t-niese  for me compiler specific is kind of UB as our code is compiling on multi platform and also whenever we change compiler or optimization settings I do not want this behavior to change! This is the reason of the question

Answer (score 2):

> can a compiler optimize this code such that `o2.GetValue()` will end up being replace by `obj->GetValue()` or some cached value ?

If the compiler can guarantee that the optimization follows the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) it can do such an optimization.

If it can do that assumption depends what is actually done in:

```
   //... much more code
   // some which may modify data pointed to by obj1
```

Comment: I think I understand the as if rule, but this code is a bit tricky:
you see the Obj pointed to by obj1 is part of a vector, the pointer cannot become invalid, but the data poited to by Obj1 is Constant for this function in the sense that the function should not modify it through the pointer.
but some calls operating on the vector could modify the data of Obj1, this is why a copy is taken. this way the person doing this code hope to have the old value available

Comment: @Daniel Anderson `but some calls operating on the vector could modify the data of Obj1, this is why a copy is taken.` if the compiler can determine that this does not happen it can do the optimization that replaces `DoSomething(o2.GetValue())` with `DoSomething(obj1->GetValue())` if it can't do that it won't do that optimization.

Comment: @DanielAnderson  If it can't do the optimization, and it can guarantee that `obj1->GetValue()` has no side effects, and `o2` is only use for that `GetValue` it could do `obj1->GetValue()` instead of `const Obj o2 = *obj1;` and only storing that value. If not it can't. That is what the as-if rule says. So what could be said more about that regarding your question and based on the shown code?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to assume that `*obj1` may [alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Strict_aliasing) another way of reaching the same object of type `Obj`.  It can't eliminate the copy unless it can track the caller and understand where the pointer is coming from or otherwise prove that this can't happen.

The `const` on `obj1` means you are not allowed to modify it via this name, but it cannot assume that it's not changed by some other name.  C++ doesn't have the `restrict` modifier available in C, but there are compiler extensions that can be used to inform the compiler that there is no aliasing, and potentially enable such optimizations.

The passage in CppReference cited above explains (for C)

> These rules control whether a function that receives two pointers must re-read one after writing through another

C++ has the same feature:  pointers can alias values of the *same type*, but it is undefined behavior to modify an aliased location if the types don't match.  C++ has a more complex meaning of "same type" in that a derived type contains a base class subobject.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, so Obj1 points to some memtable, the pointer remains valid through the function, but the memtable data can change synchronously due to some call within the function that operate on the memtable which incidentally is global!

Comment: Yes, and the compiler has to consider that possibility.  Maybe you didn't understand my answer; I said nothing about `obj1` changing to point to something else.

Comment: ok, make sense. A bit what I had in mind. But with optimizers being very good these day I wanted to make sure the data was refetch across function call.